# Azure DevOps Use Nuget task Build Failing

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Using Azure DevOps. Starting today, all builds are failing at the "Use NuGet" task:

```
"##[error]Unhandled: Unexpected token ="
```

The output from the log

[image: log]

This was not an issue before today (11/16/2018). Anyone else using Azure DevOps running into this problem? New builds and existing builds cannot be completed.

Comment: Sounds like something on the Command Line. Can you show the Nuget Task?

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of your 'Nuget tool installer' task ?

Comment: Here is the YAML:
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be some sort of issue going on with DevOps at the moment. About the same time that you posted this question, we had attempted to start a build that has run successfully in the past; the only commit edited code, nothing to the packages.config. We received the exact same error that you received here.

A few minutes ago (about an hour after you've posted this), I ran the same build again. This time it got past Nuget Restore, but failed to contact our Octopus Deploy server.

Hopefully this will work itself out, but for now I don't think it has anything to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been addressed: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/384011/nuget-tool-installer-018-unexpected-token.html